# Plot after action button is click in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to plot a graph after an action button is clicked on but It is not working, I am trying to use **observe Event()** and **Isolate()** functions

Ui. has the us and code for the same procedure. `Uioutput` is the action bar that I am calling, my intention is every output plot should occur after clicking the action button
The server contains the path to a csv file i am reading in feather format but this does not matter, what matters is action button working with plots. I have also subset ted the data `sbst.unt` and am rendering the table on shiny app.
**UI.R**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Neospec Visualization"),
  sidebarLayout(


    sidebarPanel(

      uiOutput("FaceUnit"),

      tags$hr(),

      uiOutput("FaceType")

    ),



    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Table", dataTableOutput("table"),6),

        h3("Data table view"),
        #withSpinner(DT::dataTableOutput("contents"),6),
        #dataTableOutput("tt"),
        h3("Raw Neospec signatures"),
        withSpinner(plotOutput("plts"),6)

      )

    )
  )
)
```

SERVER.R

```
    server <- function(input, output){


  neos <- reactive({read_feather("path")})


  output$FaceUnit <- renderUI({

    actionButton(inputId = "FaceUnit", label = " Unit")


  })
    output$FaceType <- renderUI({

      actionButton(inputId = "FaceType", label = " Type")

    })

  sbst.unt<-reactive({
    neodt<-neos()
    unt.sbst <- neodt[(neodt$unit==input$unit & neodt$Type==input$Type),]
    unt.sbst
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({sbst.unt()})


  observeEvent(
  output$plts <- renderPlot({

    input$FaceType

    isolate({


    plt.dt2 <- neos()

    wavelength2<-as.numeric(substr(colnames(plt.dt2[,-c(1:3)]),2,19))

    colnames(plt.dt2) <- c("SSN","unit","Type",wavelength2)

    spec.m2 <- melt(plt.dt2, id = c("SSN","unit","Type"))


    p2 <- ggplot(data =spec.m2 , aes(x = as.numeric(as.vector(variable)),y = value, group = SSN)) +

      geom_line(size = 0.1, col = "blue", alpha = 0.8) +

      ggtitle("Neospec raw spectrums ") +

      xlim(range(wavelength2))+

      ylim(c(0,1)) +

      xlab("Wavelength (nm)") +

      ylab("Reflectance") + 
      #theme with white background
      theme_bw() +
      #eliminates background, gridlines, and chart border
      theme(
        plot.background = element_blank()
        ,panel.grid.major = element_blank()
        ,panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
      )
    p2 <- p2 + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

    p2 <- p2 + theme(legend.position = "none")

    fac.typ <- p2 + facet_grid(.~Type, switch ='y', scales = "free")

    fac.typ


    })
  }))
}`


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

 dput(SSN   unit    Type    X2600.000003874302  X2597.4609457191823 X2594.926835544204  X2592.3976714178884 X2589.8734263803212
RResmicro1g3SI1 Unit1   soil    0.37285368  0.364537573 0.356995724 0.350070815
RResmicro1g3SI1 Unit2   soil    0.295855514 0.292268904 0.289343551 0.286564459 
RResmicro1g3SI1 Unit3   soil    0.296041336 0.294366508 0.292749726 0.291253321
RResmicro1mSGe2 Unit1   soil    0.387475087 0.38768638  0.387886013 0.388117495
RResmicro1mSGe2 Unit2   soil    0.428004392 0.42284043  0.41852246  0.414420365
RResmicro1mSGe2 Unit3   soil    0.422322559 0.419495941 0.416767303 0.414211552
RresMicro1mtHj  Unit1   dung    0.458153765 0.456678695 0.455340966 0.454036524
RresMicro1mtHj  Unit2   dung    0.429987543 0.429523389 0.429238502 0.428967891
RresMicro1mtHj  Unit3   dung    0.413184068 0.412489425 0.411818841 0.411190139)
```

Comment: have a look at the `eventReactive`

Comment: is there a way you can recommend I use it on the code

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Neospec Visualization"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("FaceUnitOut"),
      tags$hr(),
      uiOutput("FaceTypeOut")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Table", dataTableOutput("table"),6),
        h3("Data table view"),
        #withSpinner(DT::dataTableOutput("contents"),6),
        #dataTableOutput("tt"),
        h3("Raw Neospec signatures"),
        withSpinner(plotOutput("plts"),6)
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){

  neos <- reactive({
    read_feather("path")
  })

  output$FaceUnitOut <- renderUI({
    actionButton(inputId = "FaceUnit", label = " Unit")
  })

  output$FaceTypeOut <- renderUI({
    actionButton(inputId = "FaceType", label = " Type")
  })

  sbst.unt<-reactive({
    neodt <- neos()
    unt.sbst <- neodt[(neodt$unit==input$unit & neodt$Type==input$Type),]
    unt.sbst
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    sbst.unt()
  })

  # here you react off the FaceType button
  plotdata <- eventReactive(input$FaceType,{
    req(input$FaceType)
    neos()
  })

  output$plts <- renderPlot({
    plt.dt2 <- plotdata()

    wavelength2 <- as.numeric(substr(colnames(plt.dt2[,-c(1:3)]),2,19))
    colnames(plt.dt2) <- c("SSN","unit","Type",wavelength2)
    spec.m2 <- melt(plt.dt2, id = c("SSN","unit","Type"))

    p2 <- ggplot(data = spec.m2 , aes(x = as.numeric(as.vector(variable)),y = value, group = SSN)) +
      geom_line(size = 0.1, col = "blue", alpha = 0.8) +
      ggtitle("Neospec raw spectrums ") +
      xlim(range(wavelength2))+
      ylim(c(0,1)) +
      xlab("Wavelength (nm)") +
      ylab("Reflectance") + 
      #theme with white background
      theme_bw() +
      #eliminates background, gridlines, and chart border
      theme(
        plot.background = element_blank(),panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
    p2 <- p2 + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
    p2 <- p2 + theme(legend.position = "none")
    fac.typ <- p2 + facet_grid(.~Type, switch ='y', scales = "free")
    fac.typ
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Works so well,only challenge is its slow in ploting and output$table <- renderDataTable   is not displaying the table on shiny

Comment: provide some data please, so I can have it up. I coded this without actually running it

Comment: How can you get it...I can do that

Comment: paste the results of `dput(data)` into the question

Comment: I have done so with small piece of data,,,, its messy but the way its organized columns start with SNN, unit, Type then columns to plot, now that data i convert it to feather format, subset it and then melt. you can pick like first 4 rows to plot